# SAS - replace consecutive duplicate values

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS and searched for this specific query, but couldn't find something that addressed it. I would like to know how to to replace consecutive values with another value. If I have a variable with the following rows:

```
A B C D D D D D F R T
```

I would like to replace the consecutively repeated "D"s with 0 **(but keep the first "D")**, so that it looks like this:

```
A B C D 0 0 0 0 F R T
```

Is there a SAS function that can do this? Would I need a loop of some sort?

Thank you!

## ***Update***

I've provided some pseudocode and an example dataset below.

Example dataset:

```
data a;
input var1 $ var2 $ var3 $ var4 $ var5 $;
datalines;
a    d     d     d      c
c    d     c     d      b
a    d     a     a      d
;
run;
```

The final dataset should look like this, where only the consecutive "D" value (occurs only in the first row) is changed:

```
a    d     0     0      c
c    d     c     d      b
a    d     a     a      d
```

Below is some code I'm trying to work with, but is not getting me very far.

```
data b;
  set a;
  retain hold;
  array var(5) var1-var5;

  do i=1 to 5;
    do j=1 to 5;
      if i ne j and var(j)="d" and var(i)="d" then var(j)=0;

    end;
  end;
run;
```

What it returns is this table below (which is different from the above table that I want). Instead of replacing with 0 only *consecutive* values of "D", it is replacing any repeated value of "D"

```
    a    d     0     0      c
    c    d     c     0      b
    a    d     a     a      0
```

I think the issue is that I'm not sure how to **figure out whether there is a consecutive duplicate only, store the index range for consecutive duplicates, and then replace only the values in that specific range**. Any help on that front would be much appreciated!

Comment: There are many ways, it depends on how your data is structured which you have not clearly explained. Is your data in a single row, or are those observations in a variable. Also, please post anything you've tried as per SO rules.

Comment: As @Reeza said, your exact approach depends on how the data is stored. However, a simple algorithm would be to check if the preceding value is the same as the current; if it is, move forward until you find a new value, then change all characters in that range to a 0.

Comment: For future reference, you can find a complete list of SAS functions and call routines here:  https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67960/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0w6napahk6x0an0z2dzozh2ouzm.htm

Comment: The data is multiple rows and columns (so the "A B C D D D D D F R T" I show above" would be a column). There would be multiple columns like this. The data is not sorted in alphabetical order since it cannot be (it is date/time-sensitive so the order cannot change).

Comment: @ahjohnston25, so if I understand correctly - you're saying to create a loop such that for each column (i.e. for each variable) you check the rows to see if there is a duplicate "D", then continue checking until there is a new character - when you hit a new character, then replace all the prior "D"s except the first "D" to 0? Any suggestions on how to write a loop like this? I think I have a basic understanding of a loop but do not quite understand how I would go about testing a range, storing the range, and then changing values within that range.

Comment: @user5278831 Yes. While it's too long to give pseudocode in a comment, use a nested for loop, with the inner for loop inside an if statement checking for the first duplicate. For the range, just store the beginning index and the final index.

Comment: Thanks @ahjohnston25. I've been playing around with this and have updated my question with some example code I've been using. Would much appreciate some further guidance. I think there are quite a few blindspots in my knowledge of SAS at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go, you were close.  vote my answers up if they work for you.

```
data b;
 set a;
 drop j;

 array var(5) var1-var5;

 do j=5 to 2 by -1;
   if  (var(j)="d" and var(j-1)="d") then var(j)="0";
 end;

run;
```

The above assumes that the double d's have to occur on the same row.  If you want to count var5 on row 3 with var1 on row 4 you need to use the retain statement and "hold"

When you provide sample data try to think about the problem and show all the edge conditions.

Comment: AHA!!!! Going backwards was the key ... that really does simplify it. Thank you! Could you explain what's going on in some more detail with the "retain hold"? I'm not sure I completely understand it, though I left it in from a tutorial I was looking at.

Comment: well i might be tempted to explain if you up voted my answers

Comment: Did try numerous times. I get the following message when I do: "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: The data step sas processes a file row by row. when it goes to the next row it longer has a memory of what the previous row was unless you use the retain statement.  Confusing, if you have a variable X that's already defined on each row when it reads the next value of X it will overwrite what it has with the new value (not the old one).  However suppose X is defined and Y is not defined.  and you do a retain on Y and set Y = X.  Then you will have the new value of X and in Y you'll have the previous value of X.  Of course you have to figure out what you want to do on row 1 (when _n_ = 1).

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is fine.  here's one way of getting what you want.

```
data mydata;
score = "A";
output;
score = "B";
output;
score = "C";
output;
score = "D";
output;
score = "D";
output;
score = "D";
output;
score = "D";
output;
score = "F";
output;
score = "R";
output;
score = "T";
output;
run;

proc sort data=mydata;
by score;
run;

data newdata;
set mydata;
by score;

if first.score then output;
else do;
  score = 'O';
  output;
end;
run;
```

It looks like you have a 0 and not a O.  remember that columns are variables and rows are observations so if you want an 0 you can replace score = 'O' with score = '0' but you can not use score = 0.  The code as written always outputs the first instance and then any duplicate is changed to O.  If you just want to replace duplicate D then modify the if statement accordingly.  Hope that helps.  Good luck with learning SAS.  Took me a while and still learning

Comment: What if the original order matters? The question is unclear and doesn't follow SO rules of posting something you've tried.

Comment: well, the data supplied is sorted to begin with but good point.

Comment: @DCR - I've updated my initial question with some code I'm trying to get working. A little success so far, but still need to keep chugging along. Do check it out! Would appreciate your help!